# Using a result of an inner join as part of a query for another join

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have to use the result from one inner join table and subsequently get the records that are not present in another linking table:

[image: high level query description]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check whether a value is not in a set of values, use NOT IN:

```
SELECT *
FROM A
WHERE some_ID NOT IN (SELECT C.some_ID
                      FROM B
                      JOIN C ON ...)
```

Alternatively, use a correlated subquery, which does a separate lookup for each record in the outer query:

```
SELECT *
FROM A
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM B
                  JOIN C ON ...
                  WHERE C.some_ID = A.some_ID)
```

Alternatively, use an [outer join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Outer_join) and check which records did not match:

```
SELECT A.*
FROM A
LEFT JOIN (B JOIN C ON ...)
ON A.some_ID = C.some_ID
WHERE C.some_ID IS NULL
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay, looks like i figured it out, but it was pretty much similar to this.